# How to create an Internal database inside WPF application that doesn't require any outside connections?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, database

i am using C# WPF and created a WPF Desktop app , now i have problem exporting it to the client's computer, i am using SQL Server Management Studio 2014. Now the issue is that i want the Setup/installshield of the software to contain all the components of the said software so when i install it , it does not require extra Applications. 
 i just want to have a **database inside the finished application**. not one that connects to an external database or any outside connections but one **so all the data is readable, writeable, deletable from within the application** itself.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **SQLite** which can be found [here](https://www.sqlite.org/).

A tutorial can be found [here](http://archive.is/V5ShE).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SQL Server Express that is limited in  terms of Size ( 10Gb).

And it s easy to setup with MS installers

You'll have a connection string like :

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.mdf;
   InitialCatalog=DatabaseName;
   Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Regards

Comment: Mister Emmanuel DURIN, can you please tell me where to use this connection string please??

Comment: It goes in <connectionstrings> section of app.config. Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms130978%28v=sql.120%29.aspx